# How to install dotnetnuke 5.4

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

I am new to DotNetNuke configuration side.

I want to download dotnetnuke 5.4 and want to install on my machine.

Any help would be much more appreciated.

Thanks

**Environment**
OS Version: Win Vista
.Net: VS.Net 2008
SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help:

http://info.dotnetnuke.com/rs/dotnetnuke/images/DotNetNuke_Installation_Instructions_052609.pdf

Comment: Could you please provide me latest dnn installable and source code path.
Thanks

Comment: Everything you need is on their website at http://www.dotnetnuke.com/tabid/125/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this documentation a while ago [CLICK HERE](http://rupiqueen.com/wordpress/?p=6) for it. I also have so many useful posts on DNN check them out